# How to show correct summary with a label

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am working with tableview, a button labelled "send" to the top left, and a label to the top right position. Pressing the button yields the following results. Every 7th row will show pic3, every 3rd row will show pic2 and other rows will show pic1. 
The label on the top right shows the sum of the picture scores.
pic1 : 4
pic2 : 2
pic3 : 1

I can insert new row and correct pictures always but label doesn't show correct summary

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblRowStatus: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tblList:UITableView!
    var imgName = [String]()
    var pic1 = [String]()
    var pic2 = [String]()
    var pic3 = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tblList.tableFooterView = UIView.init(frame: .zero)
        tblList.dataSource = self
        tblList.delegate = self

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imgName.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for : indexPath)

        let pathRow = indexPath.row + 1

        if pathRow % 7 == 0{
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "pic3")
            pic3.append("pic3")
        }else if pathRow % 3 == 0{
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "pic2")
            pic2.append("pic2")
        }else {
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "pic1")
            pic1.append("pic1")
        }

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 30.0
    }

    @IBAction func addRow(_ sender: UIButton) {
        tblList.beginUpdates()
        imgName.insert("New Element", at: 0)
        tblList.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: -1 , section: 0)], with: .automatic)
        tblList.endUpdates()
        self.lblRowStatus.text = "pic1: \(pic1.count)\npic2: \(pic2.count)\npic3: \(pic3.count)"
        print(imgName.count)

    }
}
```

Comment: What label is not showing the correct?

Comment: Has tableView(cellForRowAt) been called when tblList.endUpdates is done?

Comment: button can insert new row and correct pictures always but label stops count after 25th row. when I scroll bottom of the table view I can see correct pictures in correct rows but label doesn't count correct summary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because table views only calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath` when it needs to show another row. For example, let's say your table view has 100 rows, but only 10 is visible on screen. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will only be called 10 times to get the cells that are actually visible.

As you scroll down, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets called again and again, in order to load the cells below. As you scroll up, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` also gets called, to load the cells above. This is because table views will reuse the cells at the top and put them at the bottom, so when you scroll down, the top part of the table view is literally gone, and needs to be reloaded again.

Basically, my point is, don't rely on `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to count how many of each image there are. Do the math yourself.

To calculate how many pic3's there are, do

```
let pic3Count = imgName.count / 7
```

To calculate how many pic2's there are, do

```
// remember to subtract imgName.count / 21! Those are the rows divisible by both 7 and 3, in which pic3 will be displayed
let pic2Count = imgName.count / 3 - imgName.count / 21
```

To calculate how many pic1's, do:

```
let pic1Count = imgName.count - pic2Count - pic3Count
```